# Change Google 2FA app from Gmail to another on iOS?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google-account, multi-factor-auth, ios

When logging into a Google service on the web with 2FA enabled, Google will prompt you to go to the Gmail app on the iPhone to confirm the login.

If you delete the Gmail app, it will still prompt you to confirm the login in that app, which is obviously not possible.

How do I change what app I confirm logins with to an existing Google app on my phone?

Comment: Have you already look at https://support.google.com/accounts?

Comment: Yes I have. No help in there unfortunately...